# Real cash gambling app

Tags: android, game-design, flash, server

I am making a cash game like deal or no deal for use as an android app, using adobe software.

The idea is player wagers 50 pence through Paypal plays the game wins, say, £10 pounds and then cash out.

How do I create a cash pay and play system probably with Paypal? I have done the art work and the basic flash script, i.e. actions and movie.

I will also need some sort of data feedback to prevent hacking of game, I think, and to be able to send updates and be able to remotely alter win percentages according to profits and losses.

Will the user need to be connected to a server?

Can someone help guide me through what the steps I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the first thing you need to do is ensure that the game in question is legal in your jurisdiction, and whatever jurisdictions you plan to market it in:

Gambling is often heavily regulated, and I'm not sure if PayPal allows it at all.

---

As for the technical details, what you want to have is a client-server application, to prevent fraud.

The server must hold literally *all* state, and only send to the client what is absolutely necessary to display direct responses to the users actions.

Remember that any and all data you send to the client **must** be considered compromised, and every bit of information you receive from the client **must** be considered a malicious attempt to cheat.

---

As for altering win/loss rates to ensure that you stay in the black, that part is easy, once you have all state on the server side; at least if you know how your game works in terms of profit margins.

Consider, as an example, a slot machine game:

A naïve implementation might simply generate a set of random numbers for the reel positions, and hand that off to the client, along with the winnings it generates for the given bet.

A more sophisticated approach would be to keep track of *your* global winnings, setting aside a certain portion of your profits (say, 40 %) as prize money, and generate reel settings that ensure that you never go over the prize cap, distributing the winning spins between various players more or less evenly.

The same approach could be taken for a deal-or-no-deal type game: Rather than generating the entire layout of the prize boxes up front, you generate the order in which the prize boxes are opened, in order to give the desired amount of winnings for that game.

Comment: Well, that escalated quickly.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't come across client-server applications, that's what I need to know about.

Comment: I have documented the rest of your reply as it puts what is in my head into text (: thanks

Answer (score -1):

As a game developer, you can offer your game to licensed third parties who will operate the game under a gambling license and in the Jurisdiction of their choice. In general, they will have pre-existing payment solutions etc.

If you want to offer the game for real money plays directly, you would either need to get a gambling license (the UK is pretty easy to get one) or work with a company such ours: GamblingTec.com who offer a [gambling licensing platform as a service](https://www.gamblingtec.com).

> DISCLAIMER: I work for GamblingTec.com which was designed specifically
>   to help game developers. It is one of the few affordable solutions out
>   there designed to help.